# Avoid linebreaks inside a div with dynamic width in IE

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div that would have a dynamic width depending on the content inside that div. It works well in Firefox but in IE I get linebreaks, see screenshot below:

[image]

The markup looks like this:

```
<div class="filter-dropdown">
    <div class="filter-dropdown-options-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">(Select All)
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="2010-01-31" checked="checked">2010-01-31
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="filter-btn-wrapper">
        <input type="button" value="Ok" class="btn-filter-ok">
        <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn-filter-cancel">
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS looks like this:

```
 .filter-wrapper div.filter-dropdown{
 position:absolute;
 top:-190px;
 right:10px;
 border:1px solid #CFD6DA;
 z-index:10000;
 display:none;
 padding:10px;
 height:170px;
 background-color:#EEF1F2;
}

.filter-wrapper div.filter-dropdown .filter-dropdown-options-wrapper{
 border:1px solid #CFD6DA;
 padding:5px 10px;
 height:130px;
 overflow-y:auto;
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
 width:100%;
}

.filter-wrapper div.filter-dropdown .filter-dropdown-options-wrapper ul{
 list-style:none;
 padding-left:0px;
 margin:0px;
}

.filter-wrapper div.filter-dropdown .filter-dropdown-options-wrapper ul li label{
 display:block;
}

.filter-wrapper div.filter-dropdown .filter-btn-wrapper{
 margin-top:10px;
 text-align:right;
 width:130px;
}

.filter-wrapper div.filter-dropdown .filter-btn-wrapper .btn-filter-ok{
 margin-right:5px;
 width:60px;
}
```

So, my question is - what do I have to do in order to avoid linebreaks and keep width of the outer div dynamic?

Comment: What are you going to do if the user increases the font size?

Comment: I made a quick test and this markup scales actually pretty well when increasing/decreasing font-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make your padding/margins on the right side of your inputs and that box small enough that it doesn't WANT to wrap. It's wrapping because it's running out of room. If you set the background color of the labels you'll probably see where it's ending.

Lastly as a failsafe you can set `white-space: nowrap;` but this should be a failsafe for funky font size issues and such not your primary solution because it will introduce complications of horizontal scroll bars etc.

**Edit:** Also, you need to get your `<input...>` tags out of the `<label...>` tags. The labels should be attached to the inputs by name, not by virtue of being inside them!

Comment: Well, "white-space: nowrap;" definetly fixes the problem! But if I move checkboxes outside label then I get linebrake after the input..

Comment: That's because you're shooting yourself in the foot by setting `display: block;` on your labels in the 4th rule in the CSS you posted in your question. The LI elements are already block level, that rule is superfluousness and damaging to your layout.